# Rewrite rule to end all URL's with .html including /index.html in the root and other directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My question is, How can I rewrite all of my URL's in a way that will add `.html` to the end of every URL?

here is my .htaccess rule that I have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

</IfModule>
```

I have tried adding .html to `index.php/$1.html` but this is throwing 404 all over the place.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [R=301,L,NE]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked to the certain extent, but what it has not done is it did not add .html when I entered 'codemysite.com/index', what I was expecting is to add .html at the end of the url like so 'mysite.com/index.html'.

Comment: Actually one more very minor problem, if your index in directories is not exposed like mysite.com/index.html and instead you have mysite.com/ than it shows mysite.com/.html, any ideas why?

Comment: it does not exactly impacts mysite.com but when it comes to mysite.com/directory/ then it leaves it like so mysite.com/directory/.html and leads to 404.

Comment: just tried it, but looks like it does same exact thing again for some reason, when you say /directory/ is not valid, what do you mean, because it is in my DB

Comment: That is correct, but I thought that in that case it should be rewritten to either /directory/index.html or at least /directory/, should not it?